# C++: Operator, (comma) doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I'm writing my class now and testing it. It seems that the comma operator (operator,) refuses to work, the program simply skips it. This is the code I'm running

```
fileObj << buffer,40;
```

I wrote the following operators (only prototypes shown, the code isn't relevant):

```
const file_t& operator<<(const void* buffer);
void operator,(int length);
```

the "operator<<" works fine, the program uses it but when it arrives to the "operator," , it simply skips it like it doesn't even exist. Needless to say that both operators depend on each other.

Any idea why the comma operator is being skipped? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/OverloadingtheCommaOperator.htm

Comment: @karlphillip:  There are major issues with that example (just at a glance, the overloads should be const-qualified and should take const references to their operands; the operators should be non-members to allow correct conversions of both the LHS and RHS operands, `using namespace std;` is evil).  In general, I wouldn't trust a "C++ Tutorial" from a website named "java2s"...

Comment: Glad I didn't posted that link as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<<` operator returns a **const** file_t reference. Your comma operator is a **non-const** function. Since the types don't match, the compiler does not select your comma operator to perform the operation. Instead, it uses the built-in comma operator, which simply evaluates both operands and returns the right one. (And since evaluation of the right operand has no side effects in your example, it appears as though it's not called at all.)

If your comma operator doesn't modify the object it's called on, then make it const:

```
void operator,(int length) const;
```

If the operator needs to modify your object, then don't return a const object from your `<<` operator:

```
file_t& operator<<(void const* buffer);
```

Comment: changing to "file_t& operator<<(void const* buffer);" did the trick, thanks! :) By the way, the "operator," changes the object so no const there.